# How to check if first occurrence is - (minus sign) or , (comma)

Tags: php

How to check if first occurrence is **-** (minus sign) or **,** (comma)

actually I want to explode a string if first occurrence is - (minus sign)

```
list($key, $value) = explode('-', $searchParam, 2);
```

it should explode `$searchParam = 'pattern-64587989';`

it should not explode `$searchParam = 'pattern,6458-7989';`

I do not want to explode if first accordance is comma.

I want efficient code as it is used many times on the same page.

Comment: Would the input be expected to always have either one dash, or one dash and one comma, or could it be something else?

Comment: there may or may not any of them , or -

Comment: if there is no `-` or `,` present what you want to do then ?, also in case of `-` do you will get an array and in case of comma you will get a string. is that what you want to achieve ?

Comment: 1. If there is no `-`or `,` do nothing. 2. Explode only if first occurrence is `-`if first occurrence is `,` do nothing.

Comment: in that case of `,` or non of `-` and `,` you can't have your result in `list($key, $value)` or if you do put the string in array you will get the `$key` but empty `$value`.

Comment: If both are not present or `, ` occurs first I do not need list.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply test if the first exploded part contains a comma:

```
$parts = explode('-', $searchParam);

if (count($parts) > 0 && strpos($parts[0], ',') === false) {
  list($key, $value) = $parts;  // or better: [$key, $value] = $parts;
} else {
  // Nope
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/mQX7n**

Answer (score 0):

Use variable, for example:

`$exploded = explode('-', $searchParam, 2);`

Then use if condition to count values in array:

```
if (count($exploded) > 1) {
    list($key, $value) = $exploded;
} else {
    // Something else
}
```

Comment: I do not want to explode if first accordance is comma.

Comment: If it is comma, $exploded will be array with one value and don't pass condition.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with is to first do a regex check on the input to decide whether or not it should be split.  Then, conditionally do a split if the input does not have a comma first before the dash, otherwise just keep the entire input.

```
$searchParam = 'pattern-64587989';
$vals = [$searchParam];
if(!preg_match("/^[^,-]*,[^-]*-.*$/", $searchParam)) {
    $vals = explode("-", $searchParam, 2);
}
print_r($vals);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => pattern
    [1] => 64587989
)
```

Using an input of `pattern,6458-7989` prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => pattern,6458-7989
)
```

Comment: Just spit into 2 not more.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://tehplayground.com/5BQl2eFCuJRKrlcz) you can use this to implement your conditional check.

```
// Example 1:

$str1 = "pattern-64587989";

$res = substr($str1, 7, 1) == '-' ? explode('-',$str1) : $str1;
var_dump($res);


// Exmple 2:

$str2 = "pattern,6458-7989";

$res = substr($str2, 7, 1) == '-' ? explode('-',$str2) : $str2;
var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks for the position of the two characters and checks which is first.  The main thing with using `strpos()` though is that it will return false if not found.  So this uses `?: PHP_INT_MAX` to say if the comma is not found, then set it to the maximum integer, so the comparison will think the comma is past the -.

```
$searchParam = 'pattern-64587989';
$searchParam = 'pattern,6458-7989';
// Set values to ensure they contain something
$key = '';
$value = '';
if ( (strpos($searchParam, ",") ?: PHP_INT_MAX) > strpos($searchParam, "-") )  {
    list($key, $value) = explode('-', $searchParam, 2);
}

echo $key."/".$value;
```